# Maximum of uniformal idd random variables involving the Gamma function

Tags: probability, random-variables, asymptotics, gamma-function

I need some help with evaluating a particular integral:
$$\int_\theta^1 \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 \left(x_1 - \max\{x_1,x_2-s, x_3-2\cdot s,\ldots,x_N-(N-1) \cdot s\}\right) \hspace{0.5ex}dx_N\cdots dx_1 $$

where $X_i$ $\overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \operatorname{UNI}[0,1]$, N is an integer $\ge 2,$ $0< s < 0.5$, and assume that $\theta > 0$ is some real number such that $\theta < 1-N\cdot s$.

Let me show you my approach so far. First, let's rewrite the integral:
$$\int_\theta^1 \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 (x_1 - \max\{x_1,\underbrace{\max\{x_2-s, x_3-2\cdot s,\ldots,x_N-(N-1) \cdot s\}}_Z\}) \hspace{0.5ex} dx_N\, dx_1 $$
Next lets derive the CDF of Z, which is given by
\begin{align}
P(Z < z) &\stackrel{\text{def.}}{=} P(\max\{X_2-s, X_3-2\cdot s,\ldots,X_N-(N-1) \cdot s\} < z)  \\ &\stackrel{\text{iid}}{=} P(X_2< z + s) \cdot P(X_3< z + 2\cdot s) \cdots P(X_N < z+(N-1)\cdot s) \\ &\stackrel{\mathrm{UNI}}{=} (z+s)\cdot (z + 2\cdot s) \cdots (z+(N-1)\cdot s)  \\  &\stackrel{\text{def.}}{=} s^{N-1}\frac{\Gamma(N+\frac{z}{s})}{\Gamma(1+\frac{z}{s})} := G(z)
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the Gamma function.
Next, lets derive the density of Z given by $$ g(z) = \frac{dG(z)}{dz} = s^{N-2} \frac{\Gamma(N+\frac{z}{s})}{\Gamma(1+\frac{z}{s})}\cdot \left(\Psi\left(N+\frac{z}{s}\right)-\Psi\left(1+\frac{z}{s}\right)\right)$$
where $\Psi(\cdot)$ is the digamma function.

So far I think everything is correct. What I am unsure about, is the support of Z. I wonder whether I can just say that it is given by [-s , 1-s]? If yes, then let's rewrite the integral such that:
$$ \int_\theta^1 \int_{-s}^{1-s} (x_1-\max\{x_1,z\})g(z) \hspace{0.5ex} \, dz\,dx_1$$

Whenever we have that $Z < X_1$ or $X_1 > 1-s$ the expression is $0$, such that we only consider the support $[\theta, 1-s]$ for $X_1$ and $[X_1, 1-s]$ for $Z$. Now the integral can be written as
$$ \int_\theta^{1-s} \int_{x_1}^{1-s} (x_1- z)g(z)\hspace{0.5ex} dz\,dx_1$$
Using integration by parts w.r.t the integral of $Z$ yields
$$ \int_\theta^{1-s} \left[\mathop{\big|} \limits_{x_1}^{1-s}(x_1-z)G(z) - \int_{x_1}^{1-s} (-1) \cdot G(z) \hspace{0.5ex}dz \right] \, dx_1$$
Since the upper boundary of the support of $Z$ is given by $1-s$ it follows that $G(1-s) = 1$ therefore we can further simplify the expression to get
$$ \int_{\theta}^{1-s} (x_1+s-1) \hspace{0.5ex} dx_1 + \int_\theta^{1-s} \int_{x_1}^{1-s}G(z) \hspace{0.5ex}dz \, dx_1$$
Calculating the first expression and changing the order of integration for the second expression yields:
$$ -\frac{(1-\theta-s)^2}{2} + \int_\theta^{1-s}\int_\theta^z G(z) \hspace{0.5ex}dx_1 \, dz = \frac{(1-\theta-s)^2}{2} + \int_\theta^{1-s} (z-\theta)G(z) \hspace{0.5ex} dz$$
I am unsure, whether my derivation so far was correct, especially because I am not sure whether it was valid to simply assume that the support of $Z$ was given by $[-s, 1-s]$. Lets assume it was correct, than inserting the expression of $G(Z)$ yields:
$$-\frac{(1-\theta-s)^2}{2} + s^{N-1}\int_{\theta}^{1-s} (z-\theta) \frac{\Gamma(N+\frac{z}{s})}{\Gamma(1+\frac{z}{s})} \hspace{0.5ex} dz$$
At this point I have two questions:

First, is there any chance of further simplifying this expression?

Second, is there anything I can say about the asymptotic behavior of the second part when $N$ goes to infinity? Obviously $s^{N-1}$ will tend to $0$ since s < 1. But what about the integral? My guess would be that it converges to some constant, but I have no clue of how I could show this. In addition, I think I have a problem when analysing the asymptotic behavior w.r.t. $N$ due to the assumption $\theta < 1-N\cdot s$.

Thank you guys for your help in advance! I would really appreciate it.

Update 30.01: Can anybody please confirm whether it was fine to define the support of Z by [-s, 1-s]?

Comment: Too long ... suggest you reduce your question to a couple of lines

Comment: I included my approach to show that I am simply not just asking without having done anything. The questions are at the end and actually pretty short...

Comment: I think it's a really lousy idea to use the same symbol both for the random variables and for the bound variables with respect to which you integrate. There is a reason why in expressions like $\displaystyle \int_A f_X(x) \, dx,$ one $X$ is capital and the others are in lower case. Without that distinction one could not understand something like $\Pr(X\le x),$ and there are also more complicated confusions that can result.

Comment: If $s$ is fixed in $(0,1/2)$, then $\theta \to_N -\infty$. Besides, you should use Stirling approximation/bound for your Gamma function depending on $N$. Roughly, it is $(N+s/Z)^{N+s/Z}$.

Comment: @Hardy: fixed it, your right thanks.

Comment: @anonymus: the problem is that my $\theta$ is bounded below by 0 by assumption.